# Footer with image keep all text to right of image

Tags: html, css

I have a footer which contains an image on the left and a list of items to its right.

[image]

I want to make it so that when the screen gets to narrow to display it as above the items in the list wrap so that non of the text appears under the image.

Currently if the screen is too narrow the text wraps under the image which is not what I want.

[image]

Can anyone advise me on how to do this? I did consider using flexbox but this has to work in older browser so that is not an option.

```css
#footer {
  
  }

.footer__items {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <img class="footer__logo" src="images/Owl.png" alt="Picture of an Owl">
        <ul class="footer__items">
            <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
            <li>©Copyright Owl New Zealand Limited 2015. All rights reserved.</li>
        </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to set the display of the footer to table and the children to table-cell:

```css
#footer {
  display: table-row;
}
.footer__items,
.footer__logo {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <img class="footer__logo" src="images/Owl.png" alt="Picture of an Owl">
  <ul class="footer__items">
    <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
    </li>
    <li>©Copyright Owl New Zealand Limited 2015. All rights reserved.</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  #footer .leftContent ,#footer .rightContent{
float:left;
  }
#footer .leftContent
{
  width:30%;
}
#footer .rightContent
{
  width:70%;

}
.leftContent img
{
  width:100%;
}
.rightContent ul
{
   padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

<footer id="footer">
<div class="leftContent">


  <img class="footer__logo" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/di6/eEx/di6eEx6i9.png" alt="Picture of an Owl">
  </div>
  <div class="rightContent">


        <ul class="footer__items">
            <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
            <li>©Copyright Owl New Zealand Limited 2015. All rights reserved.</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I can't use flexbox. Need it to work on older android devices.

Answer (score 0):

you could exchange the places of the items and float the links right, and to deal with the top space give it a negative margin the size of the logos height.

```
.footer__items {
    float: right;
}

<footer id="footer">
     <ul class="footer__items">
         <li><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">&copy;Copyright Owl New Zealand Limited 2015. All rights reserved.</a></li>
     </ul>
      <img src="images/owl.png" class="footer__logo" alt="Picture of an owl">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` on the image, give it a width and use that very same width as a left margin on the text

```css
.footer__logo {
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
}
.footer__items {
  margin-left: 70px;  
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <img class="footer__logo" src="images/Owl.png" alt="Picture of an Owl">
  <ul class="footer__items">
    <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
    </li>
    <li>©Copyright Owl New Zealand Limited 2015. All rights reserved.</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#footer{
 width:100%;
}
.footer__logo{
 float:left;
 width:40%;
}
.footer__items{
 float:left;
 width:60%;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="footer__logo" >
      <img src="images/Owl.png" alt="Picture of an Owl">
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer__items">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        <li>©Copyright Owl New Zealand Limited 2015. All rights reserved.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</footer>
```